# Create UIButton offscreen with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, interface-builder

I want to create a big `UIScrollView`, its contentView should contain more than 30 `UIButton`. Positions of these `UIButton` are not rectiligne and cannot be create 'programmaticaly' so I've placed all these `UIButton` on a `UIView` manually. I zoom/dezoom and scroll all over my `UIScrollView` fine **BUT** here is my problem : 
`UIButton` created offscreen is not accessible, I mean I can't click them (only `UIButton` created in the `CGRect(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 480.f)` can be click.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is that button subview to Scrollview or view ? Also why the UIButton cannot be created programatically, I didn't understand the reason.

Comment: The reason why I can't created them programmaticaly is because position is too randomly. I can, of course, create an array with all position but I will do that if I don't find any solution before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view, put a scrollView inside that view, and place your buttons on the scrollView. While adding buttons and moving them around, be certain that they're always inside the scrollView by looking at the object hierarchy in interface builder.

You can slide the scrollView around as you place things, no need to zoom. As long as your buttons are children of your scrollView it should work fine.

[image: buttons within a scrollView within a view]

Comment: My hierarchy is UIView -> {UIScrollView -> {UIView -> {UIImageView, UIButton}}} As I said, all buttons are here but only UIButtons created at offscreen don't respond to a click. I've created an UIView for my UIScrollView in order to put in a big UIImageView and all my UIButtons because I have to support zoom

Comment: Well, I've found my problem. My UIView wich contain all my UIButton and my UIImageView had a rect of 320.f,480.f and have UIButton offscreen. I just had to put it to the size of my UIImageView. wich is 1500x1500. thx anyway